# Is there a term to describe an event which happens every 18 months?

Tags: single-word-requests, time, dates, recurring-events

Obviously every year is annual.  Every two years is biennial.  Does the English language have a term for every 18 months?

Comment: What's the point of using that word if almost no one knows the meaning though =)

Comment: @Kop to sound clever ;)  I guess as @JoseK says it's interesting to introduce a new word once in a while.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[sesquiennial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesquiennial)

> ocurring every year and a half.
>
> Etymology: semi ("half") + que ("and")

I cannot find a dictionary definition of this other than Wiktionary, and 0 hits on Google NGram.

But there are some examples of [usage here](http://www.melbournemandolinorchestra.org.au/ourhistory.html)

> FAME now has responsibility for the
>   sesquiennial (every 18 months) Music
>   Festivals which attract players from
>   Europe, American continent

Comment: thank you JoseK - although my girlfriend is now debating whether it's an acceptable phrase to use in a document at work!

Comment: @planetjones: Well, he answered to your question. If are not comfortable using "sesquiennial", just use "every 18 months", it's not that bad. :D @JoseK: Where did you find it? :D ahah +1

Comment: @planetjones: Well, I only learnt this while researching your answer - dictionary.com asks "*Did you mean sexennial?*" I'll say this will have people searching in the dictionary for the meaning - so they'll have learnt something too.

Comment: @Alennano: I picked up **sesquicentennial** (which means 150 years) listed on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniversary#Latin-derived_numerical_names) and did a guess search for *sesquiennial*

Comment: @JoseK I see... Why everyone misspells my name the same way :D I need to investigate lol it can't be a coincidence. XD

Comment: I didn't find any source about how it pronounce, would be nice to add if someone finds anything.

Comment: @Alenanno: oh man, sorry about that

Comment: @JoseK, it's ok, no worries!

Comment: [Alen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alen) is a unit of measure in Danish and with the postfix nano it is quite small. However 60 cm a year is perhaps ok ;)))

Comment: OED hasn't got it; but I immediately thought it in answer to the question, and would understand it if I encountered it.

Comment: I agree with @Colin on this; it seems like the natural formation to use for this word. However, I suspect that lots of people won't understand it because they aren't familiar with "sesqui-" at all (and thus wouldn't understand sesquicentennial either).

Comment: Can this word also be used for "takes/took 18 months"? Such as "She just ruined her sesquiennial marriage"?

Comment: @planetjones the Plain English Campaign would probably have a thing or two to say about this: http://www.plainenglish.co.uk/

Comment: @Rei Miyasaka I'm not sure sesquiennial is a clear example of the  "gobbledygook, jargon and misleading public information" which the plain English campaign states they are against.

Comment: @Felix Dombek: no, something that has been around for 18 months is not the same as something that happens every 18 months.

Comment: @planetjones If you need to look up a dictionary to understand a word that might be used in a legal document when it could otherwise be described by a phrase of common words, then it might as well be.

Answer (score 13):

I think JoseK's answer is [the correct one](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28915/is-there-a-term-to-describe-an-event-which-happens-every-18-months/28916#28916), but there are also a few google hits for 'semi-triannual' and even a few for the (more correct, because unambiguous) 'semi-triennial.' Either of these might be easier for casual readers to decipher than 'sesquiennial,' since 'semi-' and 'tri-' are more familiar than 'sesqui-'.

Comment: The root is not "_sesqui-_" but "_se_" (which comes from semi-). "_qui_" is a "conjuction".

Comment: @Alenanno, I'm not talking about roots, I'm talking about English-language prefixes. 'sesqui-' may not be a single root, but it is a single prefix; it's in the [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sesqui-).

Comment: I was talking about the original term. :)

Comment: +1 not because it's the 'right' answer, but because *semi-triennial* is potentially more comprehensible to millions of people on first encounter than *sesquiennial*. I find it somewhat ironic that @Josek's only quoted *usage* example feels the need to define the term immediately after writing it! :-)