# If annual means one year, is there any word for two,three, four.. year

Tags: single-word-requests, recurring-events

From WordWeb:

```
Annual: Occurring or payable every year
```

What is the corresponding single word for occurring every two year, three year, four year etc.

I understand that it's surely not exhaustively defined for all possible year gap, but how far is it define?

Comment: Related: [Is there a term to describe an event which happens every 18 months](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28915/is-there-a-term-to-describe-an-event-which-happens-every-18-months)

Answer (score 7):

Here are the direct answers to the ones you've asked and a few more.

2 years Biennial
3 years Triennial
4 years Quadrennial
5 years Quinquennial
6 years Sexennial
7 years Septennial
8 years Octennial
9 years Novennial
10 years Decennial

[Read here for a list of more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniversary#Latin-derived_numerical_names) yearly multiples

Comment: There's also [Sesquiennial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sesquiennial) in the question [Is there a term to describe an event which happens every 18 months](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28915/is-there-a-term-to-describe-an-event-which-happens-every-18-months).

Comment: @Alenanno: and you *did* notice it was I that answered that one too ;)

Comment: ahahah no! I didn't lol