# How do you call an event which is held every 4 years

Tags: adjectives, recurring-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If annual means one year, is there any word for two,three, four.. year](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36027/if-annual-means-one-year-is-there-any-word-for-two-three-four-year)

...like Olympic Games or World Cup. Is there a word to describe their periodical characteristic or just simply "every 4 year"? There are words like `Annual`, `Biennial`, `Triennial` (every 1, 2, 3 years) but `Quadennial` seems not to be a valid word.

Comment: I see the word `quadrennial` in that question. But it does not appear in Oxford or Cambridge dictionaries. Is it OK if I use it in academic writing?

Comment: http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/quadrennial?region=us&q=quadrennial

Answer (score 3):

Quadrennial is the word.

http://www.wordnik.com/words/quadrennial

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I did answer the question. And the link is there for reference. It's not a link-only answer.